# Where to load script tags in Vue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, script-tag

I am new to Vue.js and I am simply trying to load script tags to the page, like jQuery for example. I tried adding the scripts to the end of the body in the index.html file, but they come back as 404s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>title</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- JQUERY -->         
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>         
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.0/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>         
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>         
    <script src="assets/js/tipr.min.js"></script>                               
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: try prefixing with ./ `<script src="./assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` or... `<script src="../../assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` if it's up a couple directories.

Comment: even just a slash might help: `<script src="/src/assets/js/tipr.min.js"></script>  ` you sould also move them to a static folder. What does your app-structure / IA look like?

Comment: Thanks! Moving them to the static folder worked. Can you explain the difference between the assets/static folders and when to use which?

Comment: Depends on the project config I think, https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html Pretty sure the assets folder allows for shorter relative paths. (./bg/img.png, instead of ../../assets/bg/img.png) - so it's easier to access assets throughout the app without worrying about directory navigation.

Comment: This isn't a Vue issue, this is you simply had the wrong path to the files. That would happen with anything.

Comment: Joseph was right, I had the wrong paths. There's the info on assets/static which I plan to read up on- https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Answer (score 0):

Try moving them to the `/static/` folder &/or prefixing the paths with `./` or `/`